# can't watch multiple files with json-server

Tags: json, rest, server

I've read about [Fake json-server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server) and I'd like to watch more than 1 file.
In the instructions it is listed

> --watch, -w
>   Watch file(s)

but I'm not able to make it working if I launch it as

```
json-server -w one.json two.json more.json
```

Answer (score 9):

create files as shown below

db.js

```
var firstRoute  = require('./jsonfile1.json');
var secondRoute = require('./jsonfile2.json');
var thirdRoute  = require('./jsonfile3.json');
var fourthRoute = require('./jsonfile4.json');
// and so on

module.exports = function() {
return {
firstRoute  : firstRoute,
secondRoute : secondRoute,
thirdRoute  : thirdRoute,
fourthRoute : fourthRoute
// and so on
 }
}
```

server.js

```
var jsonServer  = require('json-server')
var server      = jsonServer.create()
var router      = jsonServer.router(require('./db.js')())
var middlewares = jsonServer.defaults()

server.use(middlewares)
server.use(router)
server.listen(3000, function () {
console.log('JSON Server is running')
})
```

Now go to the directory where you have created both these files and open command line and run the code below

```
node server.js
```

That's it now go to the browser and go to localhost:3000 ,You shall see the routes that created for different files,you may use it directly.

Comment: Does this worked for you?, when I run call a route through URL it is not routing to the required path. Ex: when I call jsonfile2 in my API, actions are not triggered for the requested json.

Comment: var router      = jsonServer.router(require('./db.js')()). , works...

Comment: `POST` & `PUT` won’t persist in this case

Comment: https://github.com/typicode/json-server/issues/367#issuecomment-281523344 source of answer. its polite to attribute where you found your code

Comment: [Multiple files](https://github.com/typicode/json-server/issues/45#issuecomment-321136736)  
It is the right answer for my case. 
with _lodash_ module it works .

Answer (score 8):

You can open multipe port for differents json files with json-server.In my case
I open multiples cmd windows and launch it as.

> json-server --watch one.json -p 4000
>
> json-server --watch two.json -p 5000
>
> json-server --watch more.json -p 6000

One for cmd window, this work for me.

Answer (score 2):

It can only watch one file. You have to put the all info you need into the same file. So if you need `cars` for one call and `clients` for another, you would add a few objects from each into one file. It's unfortunate, but it's just supposed to be a very simple server.

Answer (score 2):

1 - create database file e.g db.json

```
{
  "products": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Caneta BIC Preta",
      "price": 2500.5
    },
   
  ], 
"users":[
      id:1,
      name:"Derson Ussuale,
      password: "test"
  ]
}
```

2 - In Package.json inside script

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "json-server --watch db.json --port 3001"
},
```

3 - Finally Run command > npm start

```
Resources
  http://localhost:3001/products
  http://localhost:3001/users

  Home
  http://localhost:3001
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with this things:

**Step 1:** Install `concurrently`

```
npm i concurrently --save-dev
```

**Step 2:** Create multiple json file, for an example `db-users.json`, `db-companies.json` and so on, and so on

**Step 3:** Add command line to your `package.json` scripts, for an example:

```
servers: "concurrently --kill-others \"json-server --host 0.0.0.0 --watch db-users.json --port 3000\"  \"json-server --host 0.0.0.0 --watch db-companies.json --port 3001\""
```

**Step 4:** Now you can run `npm run servers` to run your multiple json file.

After that, you can access your server with: `localhost:3000` and `localhost:3001` or with your network ip address.

**Note:** You can add more files and more command into your `package.json` scripts.

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible. JSON Server obviously works with a singleton instance of a JSON file, so it can only write and read in a single operation.

When multiple files are used, regardless of the coding techniques used for that, Json Server needs to write to a single file. Therefore, other solutions will only work for read-only.

It's more useful to use a code to merge JSON into a single file, such as a temporary file, before launching JSON Server. After JSON Server shuts down, split this temporary file and overwrite each source.

Answer (score -1):

As you can watch only one file simulteniously, because it is database, you can first read the database file and then append new data to database JSON:

```
const mockData = jsf(mockDataSchema);
const dataBaseFilePath = path.resolve(__dirname, {YOUR_DATABASE_FILE});
fs.readFile(dataBaseFilePath, (err, dbData) => {
  const json = JSON.parse(dbData);
  resultData = JSON.stringify(Object.assign(json, mockData));
  fs.writeFile(dataBaseFilePath, resultData, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }
    return console.log('Mock data generated.);
  });
});
```